# ES6/Redux: returning a function to remove event listener

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I am watching Dan Abramov's Redux tutorial on Egghead, and he does something that I am a little confused by. As a learning exercise, he has viewers rebuild the `createStore` abstraction. One method `createStore` provides is `subscribe`, which adds listeners to listen for store changes.

He then says:

> There is an important missing piece here. We haven't provided a way to unsubscribe a listener. Instead of adding a dedicated Unsubscribe method, we'll just return a function from the Subscribe method that removes this listener from the listeners' array.

So the code he uses to add/remove the listener is:

```
const subscribe = (listener) => {
  listeners.push(listener);
  return () => {
    listeners = listeners.filter(l => l !== listener);
  };
};
```

I sort of understand that this allows you to use one function for both add/remove, and that this is possible because if you pass the subscribe method the name of a listener that is already subscribed, the filter will remove it, I do *not* understand why this returns an arrow function rather than an array of listeners. How/when would this returned function be invoked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How/when would this returned function be invoked?

This function is invoked when the listener should be removed. When exactly this should happen depends on the app.

Invocation is simple:

```
const remove = subscribe(myListener);
// later:
remove();
```

> I do not understand why this returns an arrow function rather than an array of listeners.

That would allow any subscriber to mess with the listeners array, or requires every subscriber to implement the same unsubscribe logic.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this is a very common approach. For example, take a look how AngularJS [$scope.$on()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) function works. It returns a deregistration function for a listener.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good explanation and a pretty cool pattern I had not seen/noticed before!

Comment: But why not define an unsubscribe function and the component which implements the listener can call store.unsubscribe(listener). Is it because it decouples the component from the store?

Comment: @sabman: Since I'm not the creator of the library, I cannot say why this solution was preferred over another.